Autohotkey - How to open a new window when button pressed
I've done some research but can't find suitable answers. I want a button to open a new window when clicked but keep the current window open.
Here is the simplified code:
#SingleInstance, Force

Gui, Font, Normal s9, Tahoma

Gui, Add, Button, x470 y690 w20 h20 gButtonClicked, ?

Gui, Show, w500 h720, Auto Action Selector

return

ButtonClicked:
    ; Create and show a new window
    Gui, New, NewWindow
    Gui, Add, Text, , Hello
    Gui, Show
return


; Keep the script running until the GUI is closed
While (1) {
    Sleep, 100
}

GuiClose:
    ExitApp
return

It comes up with the error message that the line "Gui, New, NewWindow" was an invalid option.
I have tried ChatGPT (I'm new to autohotkey) and it could not resolve this issue.

See https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Gui.htm#New
